# How to use a factory within a factory with Laravel?

Tags: laravel, testing

I have a factory creating StreetAddresses and I want to use it in my factory that creates CreditCards.

GOOD: This behaves as expected, creating a CreditCard object with an stdClass for the street_address and the properties are all good.

```
<?php
use FuquIo\LaravelAccounting\Orm\CreditCard;
use FuquIo\LaravelCommonRelatables\Locatable\StreetAddress;
use FuquIo\LaravelUser\Access\User;

$factory->define(CreditCard::class, function (\Faker\Generator $faker){

$street_address = factory(StreetAddress::class)->make();

return [
    'customer_id'    => User::root()->getKey(),
    'cardholder'     => $faker->firstName . ' ' . $faker->lastName,
    'nick_name'      => $faker->company,
    // LOOK HERE: this works
    'street_address' => function () use ($street_address) { return (object) $street_address->toArray(); }
];

});
```

NOT so good: This returns null for the street_address.

```
<?php
use FuquIo\LaravelAccounting\Orm\CreditCard;
use FuquIo\LaravelCommonRelatables\Locatable\StreetAddress;
use FuquIo\LaravelUser\Access\User;

$factory->define(CreditCard::class, function (\Faker\Generator $faker){

$street_address = factory(StreetAddress::class)->make();

return [
    'customer_id'    => User::root()->getKey(),
    'cardholder'     => $faker->firstName . ' ' . $faker->lastName,
    'nick_name'      => $faker->company,
    // LOOK HERE AGAIN: this makes a null
    'street_address' => function () use ($street_address) { return $street_address; }
];

});
```

What I'd like, is to produce a CreditCard with a StreetAddress as a property.

UPDATE: as per the first suggested solution, I (re)tried the direct approach.  Still null.

```
use FuquIo\LaravelAccounting\Orm\CreditCard;
use FuquIo\LaravelCommonRelatables\Locatable\StreetAddress;


$factory->define(CreditCard::class, function (\Faker\Generator $faker){

//$street_address = factory(StreetAddress::class)->make();

return [
    'cardholder'     => $faker->firstName . ' ' . $faker->lastName,
    'nick_name'      => $faker->company,
//  'street_address' => function () use ($street_address) { return (object) $street_address->toArray(); }
    'street_address' => factory(StreetAddress::class)->make()
];

});
```

FYI: the debugger shows the correct class in all cases as I step thru.

Answer (score -2):

Assuming you also have a factory for `StreetAddress` then you should be able to do the following:

```
$factory->define(CreditCard::class, function (\Faker\Generator $faker){    
    return [
        'cardholder'     => $faker->firstName . ' ' . $faker->lastName,
        'nick_name'      => $faker->company,
        'street_address' => function () {
            return factory(App\StreetAddress::class)->create()->toArray();
        }
    ];
});
```

Comment: This raises an interesting point.  create() vs make()  If I'm gonna be nesting factories, I need to be careful of create()'s filling up the db with faker data.

Comment: @TarekAdam if the factory is being used for the purpose of unit testing then it can be wrapped in a database transaction and rolled back, so no records saved.

Comment: Ben makes a good point.  Laravel comes with a great unit test trait so all you need to do is `use DatabaseTransactions;` in the test class.